# Manual install of Neo4j (>2.2.2) on CircleCI

Tags: authentication, neo4j, continuous-integration, circleci

(Note: I have posted this question on CircleCI forums [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/auth-issue-for-manually-installed-neo4j-instance-v2-2-2/2406).)

I'd like to use a more recent version of neo4j than the default neo4j2.2.2 which is installed by specifying:

```
machine:
  services:
    neo4j
```

I am manually installing a newer version of neo4j using:

```
machine:
  environment:
    NEO4J_VERSION:
      "2.2.3"
  post:
    - wget dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-$NEO4J_VERSION-unix.tar.gz
    - tar -xzf neo4j-community-$NEO4J_VERSION-unix.tar.gz
    - neo4j-community-$NEO4J_VERSION/bin/neo4j start
```

Neo4j starts ok, so far so good!

Now to authenticate against neo4j, we either need to create a default user and 
define a password or turn off authentication. Neither works for me.

## Option 1: Turn off authentication in neo4j-server.properties:

(I found this method here: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/neo4j-server-authorization-error/692).

Prior to the neo4j start command, turn off the auth_enabled:

```
- sudo sed -i "s|dbms.security.auth_enabled=true|dbms.security.auth_enabled=false|g" neo4j-community-$NEO4J_VERSION/conf/neo4j-server.properties
```

Neo4j starts without auth, so connections to `http://localhost:7474` should succeed.
Instead I get:

```
httpstream: INFO: > GET http://localhost:7474/
httpstream: DEBUG: > User-Agent: py2neo/2.0.3 HTTPStream/1.5.0 Python/3.5.0-final-0 (linux)
httpstream: DEBUG: > Host: localhost:7474
httpstream: DEBUG: > X-Stream: true
httpstream: ERROR: ! SocketError: Connection refused
```

(I'm using py2neo to connect).

## Option 2: Create a default user in neo4j, and tests can use that user to authenticate:

I have a separate executable script which creates the user, then sets its password:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl -X GET http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j --user neo4j:neo4j -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json
curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password --user neo4j:neo4j -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -d "{\"password\": \"pass\"}"
```

The script is run in the `machine.post` step in `circle.yml`.
Once configured the tests should be able to authenticate using `http://neo4j:pass@localhost:7474`.
Unfortunately the curl requests fail with:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j --user neo4j:neo4j -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password --user neo4j:neo4j -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -d "{'password': 'pass'}"
...
./configure_neo4j_default_user.sh returned exit code 7

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host Action failed: ./configure_neo4j_default_user.sh
```

If I fall back and use the CircleCI default neo4j rather than manually installing, methods 1 and 2 both work. They both also work when run against a local (as in, on my laptop) install of neo4j.

Any ideas why they'd fail when run against the manual install neo4j in CircleCI?

Thanks for any help,

Craig

Comment: Have not worked a lot with CircleCI, but wouldn't it be simpler to just use the Neo4j docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j/) ? Using `--env NEO4J_AUTH=none` disables auth.

Comment: Possibly, yes! I'll check it out, thanks.